# Is it good practice to inherit from ControllerBase in Web API .NET Core 2.2?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, httpcontext

I'm creating a webapi and I wanted to create a controller that inherits from a ControllerBase class.

I'm doing this because I need to do some stuff before calling the action i.e check for the user registration and use the HttpContext.

```
public class BaseApiZrController : ControllerBase
{
    public BaseApiZrController(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {

        this.HandleAuthentication();

        //??? this.HttpContext is always null, how come?
        ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = this.HttpContext.User;

    }
    //...some code

 }
```

Is this a good practice or should I be doing all this in the start class through the middleware?

The other question, when inheriting the ControllerBase class into my custom BaseApiZrController class, I can't accesss the httpContext, it always returns null, how come?

Comment: For authentication and authorization, make sure you check out those sections in the [ASP.NET Core Security and Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) documentation. That can easily be handled through configuration (in Startup.cs), action attributes and calls to the Authorization service (for resource-based authorization) without needing to use middleware or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In asp.net core, if we create a web api controller it has `ControllerBase` by default.

If you want to do something before calling the action, you could use [Action Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#action-filters) or [Authorization Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#authorization-filters).Refer to [Implementing Action Filters in ASP.NET Core](https://code-maze.com/action-filters-aspnetcore/).

`HttpContext` is not available when the constructor of the Controller is called.
See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44683318/httpcontext-null-in-constructor).

You could use the `IHttpContextAccessor` helper service to get the HTTP context in any class that is managed by the ASP.NET Core dependency injection system. This is useful when you have a common service that is used by your controllers.

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public BaseApiZrController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;
    }
```

In startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

   // Other code...
}
```

Refer to [Access HttpContext in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-2.2#use-httpcontext-from-custom-components)